# Is it possible to create a non-fixed size array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, fixed-size-types

When creating an array like with

```
string[] list = new string[5];
```

There is a variable named `IsFixedSize`. So is it possible to create an array that is not fixed size? The only way I know is by using `List<string>`. 
I am confused because I thought arrays are about being **fixed size**, so why is there a `list.IsFixedSize`?

Comment: Because the `IsFixedSize` property is part of the `IList` interface which arrays and `List<T>` both implement.

Comment: Technically when that property was "invented" there was the `ArrayList` (that is the non-generic version of `List<>`). But it wasn't an array... It was what today we would call a `List<object>`

Comment: Obligatory [RTFM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.isfixedsize(v=vs.110).aspx), specifically: `"This property is always true for all arrays."`

Comment: @maccettura I'm sorry, I just saw the short info in VisualStudio and thought I wouldn't get more information, I will try to look things up more before posting new questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, all arrays are fixed in size. If you read the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.isfixedsize(v=vs.110).aspx) on the property though, it explains why:

> **Property Value**
>
> Type: System.Boolean
>
> This property is always true for all arrays.

And:

> [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx) implements the `IsFixedSize` property because it is required by the [`System.Collections.IList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx) interface